# Simple 'if' with 'or' statement 

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble figuring why this isn't working...

```
if (index != 10 || index != 0) {
```

If `index = 0` the function is still allowed in, why?

Comment: try the expression like this -> if ((index != 10) || (index != 0))

Comment: I think that it is impossible to make that `if` false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When index is zero, it is not ten.

The double pipe is a logical OR operator. The expression returns true when either the left, or the right side is true.

If you intend to return false when index is not 10 and zero, use the logical AND, `&&`:

```
if (index != 10 && index != 0) {
```

Comment: PS. If `index` is expected to be a true number, use `!==` instead of `!=`. `false != 0`, `[] != 0`, `[''] != 0`, `[0] != 0` and `['0'] != 0` return false, while these left sides are certainly not equal to zero.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using an OR e.g. ||. So first of all it says does index != 10 which is true since it equals 0 and it therefore proceeds into the conditional.

You would need to change it to (index != 10 && index != 0).

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it will, since using || means it will run if ANY of the 2 conditions are true. Hence, since 0 is not 10,  it will run, because when using || only 1 of the conditions needs to be satisfied.

If you want it to not be allowed, use `&&` instead of `||`, this way it will only run if both conditions are satisfied

Answer (score 1):

If `index` evaluates to a number, one of those conditions will *always* be true.

Try

```
if (!(index == 0 || index == 10)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the || with a &&.Not to get confused with the || which is OR operator and is evaluated `true` if any of the conditions are`true` while the && AND operator evaluates to a `true` if and only if all the conditions are `true`.